# Rails 4 - Paperclip refactor out has_attached_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have the validation below in 3 different models. How can I refactor it out.

```
has_attached_file :image,
                    styles: {
                      large: '700x400>',
                      medium: '400x400#',
                      thumb: '100x100#'
                    },
                    default_url: '/images/missing.png'

validates_attachment_content_type :image,
                                    content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move it to a [concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html). The hardest part about creating a concern is naming it.  Feel free to change the name, but I am going to call this concern **ImageAttachable**.  Maybe that is a silly name, but it is the best I could do on short notice.  To code this up, add the following file:

**app/models/concerns/image_attachable.rb**

```
module ImageAttachable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_attached_file :image,
                  styles: {
                    large: '700x400>',
                    medium: '400x400#',
                    thumb: '100x100#'
                  },
                  default_url: '/images/missing.png'

    validates_attachment_content_type :image,
                                  content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  end

end
```

You would then remove all of the above code from your models and replace it with:

```
include ImageAttachable
```

DHH has written [an excellent article](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns) on the subject.